# MailMerge from C# when Access mdb has password

Tags: c#, mailmerge, ms-jet-ace

I am trying to use MailMerge programatically ( from C# ). I am using an Access database file as a data source. The Access database has a password. The following code does not work for some reason even though it should. I get an invalid password textbox.

```
       WordApp = new ApplicationClass();

        WordApp.Visible = true;

        adoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ref Template,
                             ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing,
                             ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing,
                             ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing);


        Object sql = "SELECT * FROM TestMergeTest";

        Object conn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + @"C:\Documents and Settings\sebastianharko.AKA-OS\Desktop\See.mdb" + ";"
             + "Jet OLDEDB:Database Password=" + @"notpassword" + ";";

        Object password = "notpassword";

        adoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource(@"C:\Documents and Settings\sebastianharko.AKA-OS\Desktop\See.mdb", ref Missing,
              ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing,
             ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing,ref Missing, ref conn, ref sql, ref Missing, ref Missing, ref Missing);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would seem to mean your password is incorrect!!

Comment: Access database passwords have always been completely useless. Use of them indicates that somebody doesn't know what they are doing.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: Always? I hear the database password for is pretty good for ACE Access2007 because to encrypts the data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about the formatting of the connection string?  Here's an example I got by Googling 'Jet 4.0 connection string:"

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=zzyzz;
```